# How to extract the highest value in duplicates while keeping the original row names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, aggregate

I have a data.frame (9 rows and 2 cols).
It contains duplicate, triplicate values and unique values.
I want to extract unique rows with Highest values in the column 2 among duplicated and triplicated rows and the unique values from the beginning.

Here is my example:

```
df



    V1 V2
 1 "A"  "1" 
 2 "B"  "2" 
 3 "C"  "1" 
 4 "D"  "4" 
 5 "C"  "5" 
 6 "B"  "6" 
 7 "E"  "7" 
 8 "B"  "8" 
 9 "A"  "9"
```

what I want to get at the end would be something like this where 'A','B','C' have their highest value and 'D','E' are there because they were unique from the beginning:

```
  V1    V2
4 "D"  "4" 
5 "C"  "5" 
7 "E"  "7" 
8 "B"  "8" 
9 "A"  "9"
```

I could do it with aggregate but the problem is that I lose the row names at the end and it will be like this:

```
aggregate(df$V2~df$V1,df,function(x) x[which.max(x)])

   V1 V2
1 "D"  "4" 
2 "C"  "5" 
3 "E"  "7" 
4 "B"  "8" 
5 "A"  "9"
```

while I need to keep the original row names to end up like:

```
    V1  V2
4 "D"  "4" 
5 "C"  "5" 
7 "E"  "7" 
8 "B"  "8" 
9 "A"  "9"
```

Could you please help me out with my problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: FYI: When you use the formula interface of `aggregate()`, you don't need to qualify the column names in the formula. So you can say `aggregate(V2~V1,df,function(x) x[which.max(x)])` instead of `aggregate(df$V2~df$V1,df,function(x) x[which.max(x)])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(V2, V1, FUN= max)==V2),]
#   V1 V2
#4  D  4
#5  C  5
#7  E  7
#8  B  8
#9  A  9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "B", "E", "B", 
"A"), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```